# Is paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished: called after finishTransaction has been called?

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

My class observes `SKPaymentQueue`. I call:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

The documentation for `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:` states:

> "This method is called after all restorable transactions have been
>   processed by the payment queue."

Just to be overly clear, this means it's called when:

- There are no items to restore (or does this result in calling `paymentQueue:restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:`?)
- `finishTransaction` has been called on every transaction returned by the restore call.

If not correct, what is correct?

Comment: I can say that `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:` gets called before `paymentQueue:removedTransactions:`

Comment: Apparently finishTransaction does not need to be called on every transaction before this is called.

Comment: Found this in `SKPaymentQueue`: After the transactions are delivered, the payment queue calls the observer’s `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:` method. Different, and not really much more helpful.

Comment: It seems to be called after `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:`, even if `finishTransaction` has not yet been called (e.g. when `finishTransaction` is called asynchronously).